# python: Search string in a mutable string

Tags: python, regex, string, findall

I have a very long and mutable string.
Like this:

```
s = "hello today we see there? Otherwise are available tuesday 10:00 to 18:00. OK?"
```

Or this:

```
s = "hello today we see there? Otherwise are available tue 10.00 to 18.00. OK?"
```

I want as output:

```
tuesday 10:00 to 18:00
```

Or:

```
tue 10.00 to 18.00
```

I tried so:

```
print re.findall("(tuesday|tue \s\d+:|.\d+\s-\s\d+:|.\d+)",s)[0]
```

but it is not correct.

Comment: You don't actually have a mutable string because Python strings are not mutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the pattern as below:

```
tue(?:sday)?\s*\d{1,2}[:.]\d{2}\s*(?:-|to)\s*\d+[:.]\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xN1nK5/1)

Note you do not need to use the alternation, nor capturing groups.

- `tue(?:sday)?` - either `tue` or `tuesday`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace symbols
- `\d{1,2}` - two or one digits
- `[:.]` - either a `:` or a `.`
- `\d{2}` - exactly 2 digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace
- `(?:-|to)` - either `:` or `to` (note that `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group so that `re.findall` could not return this in the result)
- `\s*\d+[:.]\d+` - 0+ whitespace followed with the time (that can be written as the previous one, but most probably this will also do), `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4MRh6J):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'tue(?:sday)?\s*\d{1,2}[:.]\d{2}\s*(?:-|to)\s*\d+[:.]\d+')
test_str = "hello today we see there? Otherwise are available tuesday 10:00 to 18:00. OK?\nhello today we see there? Otherwise are available tue 10.00 to 18.00. OK?"
print(p.findall(test_str))
# => ['tuesday 10:00 to 18:00', 'tue 10.00 to 18.00']
```